# Angular 14 - How to dynamically render html/DOM when adding new item to a list

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I have a list of items I am looping through and displaying in a div. These render on initial page load.

```html
<button (click)="addCut()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Add New Cut</button>
<button (click)="addCut()" mat-raised-button color="primary">+</button>
<div class="cutcontainer" style="margin-top:10px;" *ngFor="let i of details.cutsAndPrices; let index = index;">
  <mat-form-field class="cutitem">
    <input matInput placeholder="Cut"> {{i.type}}
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field style="margin-right:15px;">
    <input matInput placeholder="Price"> {{i.price}}
  </mat-form-field>
  <button (click)="removeCut(index)" mat-raised-button color="warn" id="{{i.type}}">-</button>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way of when I click the first button, it invokes addCut(), adds an item to the list and this then updates the html on the page.

Alternatively, if easier, just add

```html
<mat-form-field class="cutitem">
  <input matInput placeholder="Cut">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field style="margin-right:15px;">
  <input matInput placeholder="Price">
</mat-form-field>
<button (click)="removeCut(index)" mat-raised-button color="warn" id="">-</button>
```

inside of the containing div when I click `addCut()`.

Hope this makes sense, Thanks in advance

Comment: Get the data and run a foreach loop on button click?

Answer (score 2):

In your .ts file:

```
addCut(): void {
  this.details.cutsAndPrices.push(price); // price is your new element you want
}
```